# Eigen modes in a room

Tags: acoustics

In a rectangular room 10*8*5 how can the eigen modes belonging to octave and third octave bands centered at 50Hz be found ? I have the formula to calculate the number of modes but don't have the idea how to find the modes. Do I need to use Matlab for it ?

Comment: Have you tried an online calculator such as  http://www.bobgolds.com/Mode/RoomModes.htm ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just have the idea but I am not able to get it completely. How is it done ? I am looking for the method and the concept behind it.